# Find app.css for wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm helping a friend with editing their site on Wordpress, and until now was under the impression that the CSS file to edit was found in `Appearance > Editor` section. But I came across the following when I went to go edit the CSS:

```
/*
*CSS Rules in this file will not be used by the theme. 
* Instead use the app.css file that is located in your themes /assets/css/ folder to add your styles. 
* If you just want to add small css snippets you might also  want to consider to add it to the designated 
*/
```

I've been searching and cannot find **app.css** file to edit the css. Where do I find this file?

Thank you!

Comment: you should really be using FTP to edit the files, not the Appearance > Editor...

Comment: You could find the file?

Answer (score 0):

You should search via **FTP** the file in this path: `wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/assets/css/app.css`